# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a vs2010 wpf application that is connecting to outlook.

My pc is windows 7 64bit with office 2003, one of my target pc is xp 32 bit also with office 2003.

I tried to update the version in the target pc and one of the application feature is to choose outlook folder, when i am trying to choose a folder from the outlook i am getting this exception :

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'

Thanks

Danny

Comment: The error you refer is usually triggered when the Office version used to developed the interop app (the object MS Office Object Library version you added to your project) is not present in the computer where the app is being executed. Are you sure that there is a working (2003) Office version in the target machine?

Comment: Pretty hard to get a dependency on that pia, VS2010 always turns on the Embed Interop Types feature.  It is not clear what you did to disable that.

Answer (score 1):

On your dev machine you've added a reference to the wrong version of the office dlls. Try removing the reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook and add it back again, but when you do, verify what version you're adding, there will likely be multiple ones. Version 12 is office 2007 and version 11 is 2003 I believe.

Comment: HI, i have tried to remove all the references and to add them until the project is compiling well. but still no go.

Comment: But did you check what version of the dlls you added as a reference?